# How to color code pandas dataframe according to frequency of elements?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, color-scheme, poker

I like to code and I like to play poker! So I am trying to make a program to keep track of my poker statistics.

I made a poker hand range table using pandas, however I am unable to color-code it according to the hands I tend to 3-bet more as compared to others.

Currently my dataframe looks like this:

[image]

I have list of hands that I want to plot in this chart(dataframe) according to their **frequency**. Let's say:

```
Hands = ["A A","K K","A Ks"....]
```

To give an idea I want my chart to look somewhat like this:

[image]

Here Yellow show hands that I 3-bet often, red shows the hands I 3-bet less often than Yellow and grey are hands I 3-bet rarely.

**EDIT**

I was able to get the result I wanted. Check out the answer section.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow (SO). Note one thing: As a rule on SO, do not post screenshot and do share code that shows your attempts.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, thank you. Luckily, I was able to get the result I wanted using heatmaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I simply calculated the percentage of hands that I 3-bet and stored it in a dictionary

```
freq_percentage = dict()
for i in freq_each:
    if(i in freq_each_raised):
        freq_percentage[i] = freq_each_raised[i]/freq_each[i]
```

Here `freq_each` stores frequency of each hand and `freq_each_raised` stores frequency of each hand that was raised and `freq_percentage` stores percentage of time I raised a particular hand.

```
matrix = [[0 for i in range(13)] for j in range(13)]

for i in freq_percentage:
    for m in range(13):
        b = 0
        for n in range(13):
            if(chart[m][n]==i):
                matrix[m][n]=round(freq_percentage[i],2)
                b = 1
                break
        if(b):
            break

hands_percentage = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
plt.figure(figsize=(14,7))
axs = sns.heatmap(hands_percentage, annot = chart, fmt = '',xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe try to use `style.background_gradient` in `seaborn`. Here is an example that you could adapt to your needs.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[3, 3] = np.nan
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan

cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)

df2 = df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
df2
```

which gives something like this:

[image]